# Pairwise independent hash functions for strings?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, hash

Many randomized algorithms and data structures (such as the [Count-Min Sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count-Min_sketch)) require hash functions with the pairwise independence property.  Intuitively, this means that the probability of a hash collision with a specific element is small, even if the output of the hash function for that element is known.

I have found many descriptions of pairwise independent hash functions for fixed-length bitvectors based on random linear functions.  However, I have not yet seen any examples of pairwise independent hash functions for strings.

Are there any families of pairwise independent hash functions for strings?

Comment: A string can easily be encoded as a bitvector. Just take the UTF-8 encoding of it. Then you can use your random linear functions.

Comment: @GregS- The problem with that approach is that the bitvectors won't be fixed-length bitvectors.  I could probably make this work by restricting the maximum possible length of the strings, but I'm hoping for a more general solution.

Comment: If this is a programming question then just try it and see how it works. If this is a theoretical computer science question then ask it over on that stackexchange site.

Comment: @GregS: Pairwise independence is pretty hard to verify experimentally.  I'm kind of curious why you think there's such a stark difference between "theoretical computer science" and "programming" --- to me, the *whole point* of doing theoretical computer science is that it informs programming decisions.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Read the FAQ for this site, and don't put words in my mouth.

Comment: @GregS:  The FAQ seems to say that this is the right place to ask questions that "generally cover [...] software algorithms."  Not all programming questions can be answered by "try-it-and-see" and it's not as if those that can't are out-of-scope here.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure they exist, but there's a bit of measure-theoretic subtlety to your question.  You might be better off asking on mathoverflow.  I'm very rusty with this stuff, but I think I can show that, even if they do exist, you don't actually want one.

To begin with, you need a probability measure on the strings, and any such measure will necessarily look *very* different from any notion of "uniform."  (It's a countable set and all the sigma-algebras over countable sets just clump together sets of elements and assign a probability to each of those sets.  You'll want all of the clumps to be singletons.)

Now, if you only give finitely many strings positive probability, you're back in the finite case.  So let's ignore that for now and assume that, for any epsilon > 0, you can find a string whose probability is strictly between 0 and epsilon.

Suppose we restrict to the case where the hash functions map strings to {0,1}.

Your family of hash functions will need to be infinite as well and you'll want to talk about it as a probability space of hash functions.  If you have a set H of hash functions that has positive probability, then every string is mapped to both 0 and 1 by (different) elements of H.  In particular, no single element of H has positive probability.  So H has to be uncountable and you've suddenly run into difficult representability issues.

I'd be very happy if someone who hasn't forgotten measure theory would chime in here.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a seed of bounded length and an output of nonzero bounded length.

A fairly crude argument to this effect is, for a finite family of hash functions H, consider a map f from an element x to a tuple giving h(x) for every h in H. Since the codomains of each h and thus f are finite, there exist two strings mapped the same way by all h in H, which, given that there are at least two possible hash values, contradicts pairwise independence.